# FTP client with a good GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, software-rec, ftp

I love linux because I get control over my system. But I do herald from the school of mac, where things are simple, beautiful, and powerful. I like it that way, as opposed to having lots of knobs and levers and everything.

**Does anyone know of a strong FTP client for linux that is in the vein of Panic's Transmit?**

It's my choice FTP software in Mac OS, but I doubt I need to convince anyone here that I don't want to DEVELOP web apps in OS X. It's a pain, imo.

Currently I use Filezilla. It works fine. But it's UI is a mess, imho.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're using Gnome on Ubuntu, why not use the default file manager (Nautilus)?

Under Ubuntu 10.04, choose “Connect to Server” in the Places menu, select “Public FTP” or “FTP (with login)” as the service type, enter the server name and other parameters (you can define bookmarks in this dialog box too), and voilà.

Comment: Nothing really comes close to Transit... but Nautilus isn't bad really, for most simple operations.

Comment: This answer still works on Ubuntu 18.10!

Answer (score 7):

I'd actually recommend sticking with Filezilla. It's one of the most feature-rich graphical FTP clients on any platform, and the GUI is continually improving.

Installation on Ubuntu / Debian / Linux Mint is as simple as `sudo apt-get install filezilla`.

Comment: For users that have limited experience (like me!) one advantage of FileZilla over Nautilus is that the first issues detailed messages of what's going on, and this can be helpful in case some problems prevent the connection. This has been helpful sometimes to troubleshoot the connection.

Comment: Fabio is correct about using Filezilla to troubleshoot a connection. Filezilla was the fourth tool I tried today--it knew how to work with a certificate error I was having.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use FTP a lot, but when I do I use FireFTP - a firefox extension. It's small, light and does job well enough

Answer (score 3):

You could try gftp. It's a simple client but it does the job well.